# VB date conversion

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, .net-2.0, date

Is there an easy way to convert a string that contains this:

```
Date: Wed, 5 Nov 2008 13:12:12 -0500 (EST)
```

into a string that contains this:

```
20081105_131212
```

**UPDATE:**
I ended up using date.tryparse which is similar to tryParseExact except you don't have to specify the format string.  I did have to eliminate the () and the EST for this to work.  The date string will always be EST because the date string comes from 1 web server.

Original string:

```
Date: Wed, 5 Nov 2008 13:12:12 -0500 (EST)
```

Using this code:

```
buff1.Remove(0, 6).Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "").Replace("EST", "").Trim()
```

Becomes this string:

```
Wed, 5 Nov 2008 13:12:12 -0500
```

Then I can format appropriately to generate my filename date using this:

```
 If Date.TryParse(buff1, dateValue) Then
   MsgBox(Format(dateValue, "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss"))
 Else
   MsgBox("nope")
 End If
```

Comment: Is this vb6, vba, or vb.net??

Comment: vb.net Visual Basic 2005

Comment: If you're going to assume it's always EST, you might as well shorten the replace to this -->   buff1.Remove(0, 6).Replace(" (EST)", "")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even better than `Date.Parse` in this case would be `Date.TryParseExact()`.  That would let you tell the framework what format you expect and return a boolean rather than throwing an exception if the parse fails.

Then use `.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")` to get the desired new string format.

Here's the format string reference, in case you need it:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Finally, I noticed you're ignoring the -500 timezone offset.  Are you sure that all your strings are really from the same time zone?

Answer (score 1):

If by VB you mean VB.NET you could use `Date.Parse` followed by `ToString()` with a format string:

```
Date.Parse(YourDateString).ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
```

Note: Remove the initial "Date: " before you parse the string.

Answer (score 1):

For a pure VB solution I would go

```
Function ConvertDateString(ByVal Original As String) As String
    Dim Elements As String() = Split(Original, " ")
    Dim DateString As String = Elements(3) & " " & Elements(2) & " " & Elements(4) & " " & Elements(5)
    Return Date.Parse(DateString).ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmsss")
End Function
```

You could eliminate DateString by just using the concatenated string in the Parase. It will fit on one line if your resolution is  1024 by 768 or bigger.

Answer (score 0):

`Format(date, "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")`

More help on [format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59bz1f0h(VS.71).aspx) function.

Comment: Those should be upper case H's.

Comment: Also, this would work with a date object, but the question is relating to a specifically formatted string with extra info that needs cleaned out.

Answer (score 0):

Like @splattne's solution in VB.NET, but with the cleanup as well...

```
Dim strDateVal As String = "Date: Wed, 5 Nov 2008 13:12:12 -0500 (EST)"
strDateVal = strDateVal.Substring(strDateVal.IndexOf(", ") + 2, strDateVal.Length - strDateVal.IndexOf(", ") - 2)
strDateVal = strDateVal.Substring(0, strDateVal.LastIndexOf(" ")).TrimEnd
Dim DateVal As Date = Date.Parse(strDateVal)
Dim NewStringVal As String = Format(DateVal, "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
```

NOTE: This ignores the timezone in order to match your expected result (per the example data in the question)

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim strDateVal As String = "Date: Wed, 5 Nov 2008 13:12:12 -0500 (EST)"

strDateVal = strDateVal.Substring(strDateVal.IndexOf(", ") + 2, 
strDateVal.Length - strDateVal.IndexOf(", ") - 2)

strDateVal = strDateVal.Substring(0, strDateVal.LastIndexOf(" ")).TrimEnd

Dim DateVal As Date = Date.Parse(strDateVal)
Dim NewStringVal As String = Format(DateVal, "ddMMyyyy_HHmmss")
```